# Trying to communicate between two processes with pipe() breaks the program

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I'm trying to communicate between two processes in C using a pipe.  Everything works fine until it is supposed to print "hi\n". The output is

```
(8841) Child here stopping self
(8841) SAYS: 19
DATA WRITED
C: 8
(8841) CONTINUING
```

This is a simplified version of the program. I know for a fact the reading part works, but it seems that the writing call does not, because it never prints "hi\n". Any clues on why is that?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t sigchld = 0;

void sigchldHandler(){
    sigchld = 1;
    return;
}

int main(){

    sigset_t mask,prev;
    signal(SIGCHLD, sigchldHandler);
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);

    int pid = fork();

    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &prev);
    if (pid == 0){
        dup2(STDIN_FILENO,fd[0]);
        printf("(%d) Child here stopping self\n",getpid());
        raise(SIGSTOP);
        printf("(%d) CONTINUING\n",getpid());
        char* hello = malloc(sizeof("hi\n"));
        read(STDIN_FILENO,hello,sizeof("hi\n"));
        printf("%s",hello);
        exit(0);
    }
    sleep(0.1);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev,NULL);
    while(1){
        if (sigchld){
            int status;
            int p = waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG|WUNTRACED);
            if (WIFSTOPPED(status)){
                if (WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGSTOP){
                    printf("(%d) SAYS: %d\n",p, WSTOPSIG(status));
                    kill(pid,SIGCONT);
                    printf("DATA WRITED\n");
                    char* h = "hi\n";
                    int c=write(fd[1],h,sizeof(h));
                    printf("C: %i\n",c);
                    break;
                }
            }
            sigchld = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(h)` is wrong. That's effectively `sizeof(char *)`. Need to use `strlen`.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Primary problem

Your key problem is that you call `pipe()` *after* you've called `fork()`.  That means the two processes have completely separate pipes; they are not talking to each other.

#### Secondary issues

There are other issues too, of course.

- You have (in the parent): `int c=write(fd[1],h,sizeof(h));`.  You're writing 8 bytes (your output includes `C: 8` because the variable `h` is a pointer of size `8` (you're on a 64-bit system).  However, the string only points to 4 bytes — you should be using `strlen()` or thereabouts to limit the amount of data written.
- You aren't closing enough file descriptors for comfort.
- You have the arguments to `dup2()` reversed.   This too is crucial.
- It seems weird to be using dynamic allocation for just 4 bytes of data, but it should work.
- You should print the PID along with the value in `hello` in the child (for consistency, if nothing else).  It's good you do that with the other printing.
- The parent should probably wait for the child after the loop (after closing the pipe).
- The `sleep()` function takes an integer; calling `sleep(0.1)` sleeps for zero seconds.  For sub-second sleeping, you need [`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) or maybe. `usleep()` (older, no longer part of POSIX, but widely available and easier to use).

Here's working code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t sigchld = 0;

static void sigchldHandler(int signum)
{
    sigchld = signum;
}

int main(void)
{
    sigset_t mask, prev;
    signal(SIGCHLD, sigchldHandler);
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);

    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    int pid = fork();

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &prev);

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        /* Child */
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        printf("(%d) Child here stopping self\n", getpid());
        raise(SIGSTOP);
        printf("(%d) CONTINUING\n", getpid());
        char *hello = malloc(sizeof("hi\n"));
        int nbytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, hello, sizeof("hi\n"));
        printf("(%d) received %d bytes: %.*s\n", getpid(), nbytes, nbytes, hello);
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Parent */
    close(fd[0]);
    nanosleep(&(struct timespec){.tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 100000000}, NULL);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev, NULL);
    while (1)
    {
        if (sigchld)
        {
            int status;
            int p = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED);
            if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
            {
                if (WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGSTOP)
                {
                    printf("(%d) SAYS: %d\n", p, WSTOPSIG(status));
                    kill(pid, SIGCONT);
                    char *h = "hi\n";
                    int c = write(fd[1], h, strlen(h));
                    printf("DATA WRITTEN: %i\n", c);
                    close(fd[1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            sigchld = 0;
        }
    }
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
(66589) Child here stopping self
(66589) SAYS: 17
DATA WRITTEN: 3
(66589) CONTINUING
(66589) received 3 bytes: hi

PID 66589 exited with status 0x0000
```

The difference between 17 (on a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.6) and 19 (on a Linux box) is normal; the actual values for signal numbers is not standardized by POSIX (though signals 1 `SIGHUP` through 15 `SIGTERM` are the same across systems because they were standard in 7th Edition Unix).